# pip ssl certificate for extra-index-url index only

Tags: ssl, pip, ssl-certificate

I've set up an internal pypi server for internal projects.

It's hosted at `https://<USER>:<PASS>@<INTERAL>/pypi` with a self-signed certificate.

I can get pip to use this repository in addition to the central pypi server using `extra-index-url` in `~/.pip/pip.conf`. As the certificate to my server is self-signed, and pip isn't using the system-wide (keychain) certificated, I've made it aware of it using `cert = ...` in the config file:

```
extra-index-url = https://<USER>:<PASS>@<INTERAL>/pypi
cert = /path/to/cert.pem
```

Now, whenever I install something using `pip install`, I get a warning that the certificate can't be verified for `https://pypi.python.org`:

```
$ pip install <PACKAGE-NAME>
Collecting <PACKAGE-NAME>
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/<PACKAGE-NAME>/: 
  There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: 
  CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590) -
  skipping
```

Is there any way to tell pip only to use the self-signed certificate *only* for the extra-index-url repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pip uses it's certificate bundle (a file) that can be found by running:

```
python -m pip._vendor.requests.certs
```

The bundle is just a file with certificates concatenated, one after another. We want to tell pip to use those AND our certificate,
so generate a new file using

```
cat $(python -m pip._vendor.requests.certs) /path/to/my/cert.pem > /path/to/my/bundle.pem
```

and make sure your `.pip/pip.conf` file contains something along these lines:

```
[global]
extra-index-url = https://user:pass@my-pypi.com
cert = /path/to/my/bundle.pem
```

Finally, you might want to periodically update `/path/to/my/bundle.pem` (in a cronjob or whatever).

### Other notes

I also got the following error:

```
SubjectAltNameWarning: Certificate for my-pypi.com has no `subjectAltName`, falling back to check for a `commonName` for now. This feature is being removed by major browsers and deprecated by RFC 2818. (See https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/497 for details.)
```

Normally, you'd create a certificate something like:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -key my.key -out cert.csr -days 365
```

Instead, copy your `openssl.cnf` (possibly in `/etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf`) to your working directory, and add an extension by adding the following to the end of the file:

```
[ san_env ]
subjectAltName=DNS:mypypi.com
```

and generating your certificate with

```
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -key my.key -out cert.csr -days 365 -config openssl.cnf -extensions san_env
```

In addition, pip wants your certificate in a different format, which can be generated using

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in cert.cer -out cert.pem
```

This file `cert.pem` can be concatenated with the python ca bundle as described above to generate your custom bundle.